# Interrupt a JSF Ajax request

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I have a JSF application, in which a RichFaces modal panel is shown using `a4j:status` while an ajax request is being handled by my backing bean.  I want to put a cancel button on the modal panel so a user can interrupt the request.

What is the best way to do this?  I'm thinking of something like having the cancel `a4j:commandButton` call an action on the bean to run `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse()` but not sure that's wise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way is that the executing method in the managed bean [i.e on server side] which is in progress during your ajax call must be written in a way that it could be aborted so that it just returns thus ending the request.This would also maintain proper server side state.

Comment: thanks - so if I bind another method to the cancel which in the bean has power to interrupt the processing would that be the best way?